# Page Reload Fail When Using Html5 Mode True in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a problem, I did remove `#!` in my URL with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. I checked my page is good if I switch in another page. But, if I reload my page like `http://example-page/thread` or `http://example-page/answer`. My page is `404 not found`. I dont know what happened. Do you know ? Please give me solution. Thanks.

**I use html 5 mode in config**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**This is my base href in index.html**

```
<base href="http://project/admin/">
```

**I use ui-sref**

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
                        <a ui-sref="home">
                            <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="title">Home</span>
                            <span class="selected"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active">
                        <a ui-sref="thread">
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="title">Thread + Answer</span>
                            <span class="selected"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

**This is my config**

```
app.config(function(stateHelperProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    stateHelperProvider        
        .state({
            name: 'home',
            url : '/',
            controller: 'admin-rv-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'thread',
            url : '/thread',
            controller: 'thread-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-thread.html',
        })
        .state({
            name: 'answer',
            url : '/answer/:id',
            params : {
                id  : null
            },
            controller: 'answer-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-answer.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'tag',
            url : '/tag',
            controller: 'list-tag-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-tag.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'form-tag',
            url : '/edit-tag/:id',
            params : {
                all : null,
                id  : null
            },
            controller: 'form-tag-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/form-tag.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'trending-tag',
            url : '/trending-tag',
            controller: 'list-trending-tag-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-trending-tag.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'form-trending-tag',
            url : '/edit-trending-tag/:id',
            params : {
                all : null,
                id  : null
            },
            controller: 'form-trending-tag-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/form-trending-tag.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'category',
            url : '/category',
            controller: 'list-category-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-category.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'form-category',
            url : '/edit-category/:id',
            params : {
                all : null,
                id  : null
            },
            controller: 'form-category-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/form-category.html'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'user',
            url : '/user',
            controller: 'user-controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/table-user.html'
        });
```

Comment: how do you run the app? what http server are you using and what configs do you have there?

Comment: I just run with `http://project/admin/`. I edited my code, check my config